# When I try to install a package in Laravel using composer the following error occurs

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php

```
./composer.json has been updated
Deprecation warning: require-dev.require is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]?|-{0,2})[a-z0-9]+)*$". Make sure you fix this as Composer 2.0 will error.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package require could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install consoletvs/charts 5.4.0
```

Does anyone know the reason for this and how to fix it? It happened for several packages,when I try to install and at some point it shows the package is there on composer.json. but then results in reverting back to the previous state.

Comment: What command are you trying to run? and / or include composer json

Comment: composer require "consoletvs/charts:5.*"

to use charts on my project.

Comment: It looks like you typed "consoletvs/charts:5.*" instead of "consoletvs/charts": "5.*" (mind the space and the quotes). But if you could post your composer.json that would be very helpful!

Comment: I posted it as a comment. since it said the comment is too long

Comment: Please add the exact command you are running to your question by editing it. Additionally, share your attempts to resolve the problem